# How to open, edit child and save to file in simple XML php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is my code

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$data -> mysuname = $_POST["mysqluname"];
$data -> myspwd = $_POST["mysqlpwd"];
$data -> mysdb = $_POST["db_name"];
$data -> saveXml();
```

But when I open the data.xml I couldn't find these values
But echoing $_POST[variable] prints the value, so its not null

I figured out that, the problem is with SELinux in fedora, I disabled it and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this :

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$data -> mysuname = $_POST["mysqluname"];
$data -> myspwd = $_POST["mysqlpwd"];
$data -> mysdb = $_POST["db_name"];
$data -> asXML("data.xml");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Comment: Thanx for the quick rly I've already tried tht it gives an error here is the error ` Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(data.xml) [simplexmlelement.asxml]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/new/createdb.php on line 88 `

Comment: @pahnin: Seems like saveXML() is an alias of asXML(). Try backing up your file, then do a `file_put_contents('data.xml', 'abcd')` and see if php complains about not being able to write to that file.

Comment: ok so it seems to be the permissions on your file aren't ok, try to "chmod" it

Comment: @salman-a same error Warning: file_put_contents(data.xml) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/new/createdb.php on line 89

Comment: @pahnin: definitely permission problem, nothing to do with simplexml. Try changing permissions on the file via PHP (or FTP). Another possible solution is to delete the file (make backup!) and create an empty file via php `file_put_contents('data.xml', '');`. The file created via PHP will always be readable/writable by PHP.

Comment: @damdec Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Permission denied in /var/www/html/new/createdb.php on line 83 :( I think its the problm with SElinux on my fedora. I'll chk tht thnx all BTW

Comment: @salman no file_put_contents nt worked too, its the problem with selinux in my fedora I turned it off and evrything is fine @all thanx fr the help